# Getting Chrome's current domain name in Typescript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome-extension, typescript, angular

I'm trying to get the currently displayed url from an Angular2 Typescript Chrome Extension.
I've read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14796722/javascript-google-chrome-extension-getting-domain-name) in order to get the url, and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12710962/calling-javascript-directly-from-typescript) regarding how to call Js functions in Ts.
I also set allowJs to true in my tsconfig.json.

Here's my code :

```
  ngOnInit(){
    declare var tabs = chrome.tabs.query({params...},function(tabs) {
      return tabs[0];
    });
    console.log(tabs());
  }
```

This doesn't compile unless I remove the log.

I also tried not to use a [function expression call](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10807348/javascript-calling-function-expression) :

```
declare chrome.tabs.query({'active': true, 'windowId': chrome.windows.WINDOW_ID_CURRENT},
      function(tabs){}
    );
```

But it didn't work at all. 
I was wondering whether it could be async related, because the code is in the OnInit.

Any ideas ?

Thanks !

Comment: Why do you use `declare`? I'm pretty sure that it's not what you want. Declaring a variable means "there's a variable with this name and type, but it's defined somewhere else, so no worries dear compiler". But in your example you are assigning the value right there.

Comment: Well, one of the links recommends to do so when calling Js functions in Ts.

Comment: There's not really such a thing as "calling js from ts" as typescript is javascript. The problem is that the compiler won't recognise `chrome.tabs.query` because it's not defined for it, so you can either declare that or use a definition file which define it for you. BUT when you assign the result of such a function to a variable, that variable shouldn't be `declared` but it should actually be there.

Comment: Thanks, it worked.

Comment: @Xan, question edited. Thanks for the notice.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved it thanks to Nitzan's comment. Here is the code :

```
declare private getUrl(){
    chrome.tabs.query({}, function(tabs) {
       console.log(tabs[0]);
    });
  }

ngOnInit(){
  this.getUrl();
}
```